# Why is "p" not formatting in "<p></p>" when i write "p" and tap the TAB key? It applies to many other html elements as well

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have stumbled onto this problem while writing the HTML code for a website. Whenever i write tags like "p","img","b from body" and other, the firs option of formatting is always wrong. This wasn't happening until yesterday. I might have set some wrong settings.

http://prntscr.com/n2oq39
http://prntscr.com/n2oqco

When i write "p", "b" from "body" or "i" from "img" i expect to have the first option of formatting "`<p></p>`" and respectively "`<body></body>`", but the actual formatting is "`<div class="post-body"></div>`" and "`<figure class="feature-image"><img src="image" alt=""></figure>`"

I would like to know what should i do in order to auto format the tags in the classic way. I can't code like this. Always having to press down-arrow key to get to the normal formatting. I have tried disabling and uninstalling all extensions from Visual Studio Code and also tried reinstalling the program itself. None of these worked.

Comment: I would like to know what should i do in order to auto format the tags in the classic way. I can't code like this.. always having to press down-arrow key to get to the normal formatting...I have tried disabling and uninstalling all extensions from Visual Studio Code and also tried reinstalling the program itself. None of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to make it right. I wrote `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none"` in the settings of Visual Studio Code.